How can I write the type of a function that returns a dynamically imported class?
I have a Python function that looks like this
def my_function() -> Any:
  from optional_dependency import SomeClass
  # This will fail if `optional_dependency` is not installed, I'm good with that.
  return SomeClass()

I'm not a huge fan of this function, but I've inherited it and I can't break it (just yet). I wonder if there is a better return type than Any.
Pyright complains whether I write

-> SomeClass
-> "SomeClass"

And Ruff complains if I write

-> "SomeClass": # type: ignore

Is there anything that can keep both Pyright and Ruff (and ideally mypy) happy?

from __future__ import annotations / if TYPE_CHECKING: from optional_dependency import SomeClass / def my_function() -> SomeClass: should work. IIRC, this has been asked before; I'll find a duplicate.

Some possible targets: Python type hinting without cyclic imports, Avoiding circular imports with type annotations in situations where __future__.annotations is insufficient, Getting NameError for annotation even if I use TYPE_CHECKING import. While none of these perfectly fits, they are about the same underlying problem: Using a type-checking-time-only symbol in type hints.

This question is similar to: Getting NameError for annotation even if I use TYPE_CHECKING import. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could also define an interface (ABC in python) that is implemented by SomeClass. Then you can have my_function return ThatInterface instead

InSync : but that's going to fail if the dependency is not present. My problem is not about circular dependencies, it's about optional ones.

Wombatz : I cannot modify optional_dependency, so that doesn't feel likeaan option.

Found an exact dupe: How to type hint with an optional import?

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from optional_dependency import SomeClass

def my_function() -> "SomeClass":
  from optional_dependency import SomeClass
  return SomeClass()

If you've used from __future__ import annotations, you can usually skip the quotes. See also https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html
